# How to test if a string exists in a file and if so, check the remaining lines in the file for another string with bash shell

Tags: bash

I already have a log say file.txt.

I will like to check in Bash, if a string (July) exists in the log and if so, check the remaining lines in the log for another string (foobar).

Comment: the "remaining lines" in Q, you meant the lines **after** the "July" line, right?

Comment: yes, immediately after "July"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have awk available, an awk oneliner could do it for you:

```
awk '/July/{f=1} f&&/foobar/{print "Found foobar after July!";exit}' file
```

if no `July` or no `foobar after July`, the command prints nothing. of course you could make an if-else, to let it print "not found" or something.